# download file to Documents directory

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdocumentdirectory

I'm trying to copy a downloaded file to a specific folder in the app's documents directory but can't seem to get it working. The code I'm using is:

```
NSString *itemPathString = @"http://pathToFolder/folder/myFile.doc";
NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:itemPathString];

NSArray *paths = [fm URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];

NSURL *folderPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"folder"];
NSURL *itemURL = [documentsPath URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile.doc"];

// copy to documents directory asynchronously
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSFileManager *theFM = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSError *error;
    [theFM copyItemAtURL:myUrl toURL:itemURL error:&error];
    }
});
```

I can retrieve the file OK but can't copy it. Can anyone tell me if there's anything wrong with the above code?

Comment: Is the `itemPathString` supposed to point to a local file, or a file on a remote server?

Comment: Hi Rob, it's supposed to point to a file on a server.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be using `NSFileManager` to download it, but rather something like [`NSURLConnection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Ah, OK. I didn't know that, thanks. I'll look into it. However, it seems to be downloading fine, just not copying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If downloading a file from a server, if it's a reasonably small file (e.g. measured in kb, not mb), you can use [`dataWithContentsOfURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-BBCGJEAC). You can use that method to load the file into memory, and then use the `NSData` instance method `writeToFile` to save the file.

But, if it's a larger file, you will want to use [`NSURLConnection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which doesn't try to hold the whole file in memory, but rather writes it to the file system when appropriate. The trick here, though, is if you want to download multiple files, you either have to download them sequentially, or encapsulate the `NSURLConnection` and the `NSOutputStream` such that you can have separate copies of those for each simultaneous download.

I have uploaded a project, [Download Manager](https://github.com/robertmryan/download-manager) that demonstrates what a `NSURLConnection` implementation might look like, but it's non-trivial. You might rather want to contemplate using an established, third-party library, such as [ASIHTTPRequest](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tree/) or [RestKit](http://restkit.org).

Comment: How small is reasonably small? =)
Most of the files I'll be dealing with are under 1MB, although a few are around 500MB.

Comment: Outstanding, sir. Thank you.

Comment: Rob, that's awesome! Just copy&pasted your code example in my project and it works instantly! Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm just wondering how can i pass the downloaded file to an method after it was saved on the folder? i can't figure out how to pass the downloadFilePath to my method after connectionDidFinishLoading. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: @rockstarberlin Two common approaches. 1. delegate/protocol pattern that defines protocol of the callback, add `delegate` property to the downloader, whatever kicks off the downloader (a) conforms to protocol; and (b) sets itself to be the downloader's `delegate`; and (c) have `connectionDidFinishLoading` invoke the delegate's callback method; or 2. use `NSNotificationCenter` notifications (where the downloader calls `postNotificationName` and the the class that's waiting for downloads to finish use `addObserver` for that notification). Obviously, you have `connectionDidFinishLoading`, too.

Comment: @Rob: I tried to fix that inside of connectionDidFinishLoading. But then i miss the reference to the downloadFilePath. Especially when downloading several zips at same time asynchronously. So i don't know which call of - (void)downloadFile belongs to which zip. Perhaps it is a bad idea to put the calling method and the - (void)downloadFile inside of the same class? I'm sending the download infos with a NSNotification to this class. But it seems that it is the better approach to implement a delegate as you suggested in the calling class. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: @Rob: This works really well for what I was trying to do. I've customised it a smidgen and now have files being stored in appropriate folders within the app's document folder. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Rob: I also put the "create the download file stream" part inside an if clause, `if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:downloadFilePath])` so it only writes the files if they don't already exist. Does that seem a reasonable approach?

Comment: Thanks again Rob. I'm just learning iOS (about a month now) and these tips are both helpful and appreciated.

Comment: @Rob: I've only just got around to looking at this again and it seems the copied files are 0kB, despite the "File Write Succeeded" message. Is that what you meant by "successfully completed"?

Comment: @Rob: thanks for the reply. The URL I'm saving to is:`/Users/User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/3CB7018E-8097-4899-B287-F04AEBAB88E4/Documents/mySubFolder`

Comment: OK - I'll have to look over the code again. BTW, thanks for your time and effort here. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I should perhaps add that the files "look" as though they've downloaded. That is to say the pdf files are listed in finder as pdf files, but if you select one its size is Zero bytes.

Comment: Ah - yes, I'm trying to download the entire directory (and check for duplicates).

Comment: Looks like I've a bit of a reading to do. =) Thanks again Rob.

Comment: @Rob: Just gone through this and it worked wonderfully. Thank you very much indeed, sir.

Comment: @Robert I know it was a little painful. You demonstrate persistence (no pun intended)!

Comment: @Robert FYI, I've pushed this out to [github](https://github.com/robertmryan/download-manager), have significantly improved the error handling, and have added another delegate protocol method for updating the view controller for the progress of updates (which you might not need, but it can be useful if you're doing something like showing a `UIProgressView`, such as my demo). Just a FYI.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to access a folder with a given name you should check if it exists and if not create it. That could quite easy be done like this:

```
NSString *folder = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:folderName];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:folder]) {
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:folder withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
}
if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Some error: %@", error);
    return;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to check if the folder was created properly on your device got to Organizer -> Devices -> [YourDevelopingDeviceWhereTheAppWasInstalled] -> Applications -> [YourApplication]

In the lower section you should at least see some folders like Documents. And if successful your created folders as well.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This created the folder in my documents directory which is more than I've managed so far.

Comment: I'm going to be retrieving files from several folders and displaying them in corresponding views. Should I create a subfolder for each category in the Documents directory or just store all the files in a single folder?

Comment: Probably it would be possible both. But i think it is much more convenient to create folders for each category. You can obtain doulbe file names, check if a category contains the correct data. I think even your code could be more readable. Thats exactly what i´ve done in my current sound playing project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create any intermediate directories prior to copying files. Check in the Simulator folder to see wether the "folder" directory is created in the applications Documents-folder.

Path to simulator is /Users/$username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/

Comment: Nothing visible from Finder in the application's Documents folder.